# org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.javaCompletionProposalComputer is not trigger when i press CTRL+Space

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

i am developing eclipse rcp 3.x application where I am Using Eclipse Luna. My editor is extending [CompilationUnitEditor](https://www.cct.lsu.edu/~rguidry/ecl31docs/api/index.html?org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/javaeditor/CompilationUnitEditor.html) and for content assist i am using org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.javaCompletionProposalComputer this plugin. But whent i pressed CTRL+Space this plugin in not invoking.
Window>javascript>content assist>editor>advance checked js proposal

```
<extension
        id="jsproposal"
        name="JS proposal"
        point="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.javaCompletionProposalComputer">
         <javaCompletionProposalComputer
      class="com.snc.contentAssist.CustomCompletionProposalComputer"
      categoryId="org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.textual_proposals"
      activate="true">

   </javaCompletionProposalComputer>
  </extension>
```

Comment: `CompilationUnitEditor` is an **internal** class, you should not be extending it.

Comment: so how to use this class ... can you please provide me any refrences ..

Comment: The only supported way to use `CompilationUnitEditor` is to use the various extension points it defines. [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html)

Comment: One more thing ..it works perfectly for .js editor but it not invoked for my own editor like .ss or .sis